# Consumir servicios WSDL con laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel-5, wsdl

Buen día vengo usando Laravel 5.6, y mi proyecto debe consumir un servicio web basado en SOAP (WSDL). Mi pregunta puntual es: ¿es posible hacerlo con Laravel y si tuvieran algún tutorial o documentación para revisarlo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Buen día. Claro, es posible, yo he consumido mandantes de SAP que son a través de WSDL desde laravel 5.4 y con la librería nativa `SoapClient`.

Como primer requisito es habilitar la extensión `php_soap.dll` en el `php.ini`. También es importante conocer las estructuras de las fuentes WSDL ya traen "métodos" que puedes invocar. A continuación un ejemplo pequeño que envía datos en formato de array a un WSDL para fines contables.

```
// Creamos los datos de entrada
$asiento = [
    'ubicacion1' => [
        'total' => 3000,
        'moneda' => 'USD'
     ],
     'ubicacion2' => [
        'total' => 4000,
        'moneda' => 'USD'
     ]
];

// Este es el webservice que vamos a consumir
$wsdl = 'http://server1.com/sap/bc/srt/wsdl/flv_10002A101AD1/prueba';

// Creamos el cliente SOAP que hará la solicitud, generalmente están 
// protegidos por un usuario y una contraseña

$cliente = new \SoapClient($wsdl, [
            'login' => 'usuario',
            'password' => 'contraseña',
            'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
            'trace' => true
        ]);


// Consumimos el servicio llamando al método que necesitamos, en este caso
// calcularCostos() es un método definido dentro del WSDL 

$resultado = $cliente->calcularCostos($asiento);

// Finalmente muestras la respuesta 
dd($resultado);
```

Es un ejemplo básico, pero funcional.